# Sum subtract with SubQuery with count throw error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running Oracle 11G. I need to run a query that SUM and then subtract the COUNT using.

```
select sum(MyColumn1) -  
(SELECT count(*) FROM MOL.Table2 e WHERE e.MyColumn2=t.Column4)
from mol.Table1 t where t.Column3=SomValue;
```

But it throws `SQL Error [937] [42000]: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`.

Comment: do you have select any other's column in your query or just it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTE helps & is easy to read; an example based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> with
  2  tsum as (select sum(e.sal) csum
  3           from emp e
  4          ),
  5  tcnt as (select count(*)   ccnt
  6           from dept d
  7           where d.deptno <= 30
  8          )
  9  select csum - ccnt
 10  from tsum cross join tcnt;

 CSUM-CCNT
----------
     29022

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write it as:

```
SELECT
  (select sum(MyColumn1) from mol.Table1 where Column3=SomValue) -
  (SELECT count(*) FROM MOL.Table2 e WHERE e.MyColumn2=73  )
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

use another aggregation

```
select sum(MyColumn1) -  
sum((SELECT count(*) FROM MOL.Table2 e WHERE e.MyColumn2=73))
from mol.Table1 where Column3=SomValue;
```

because your `(SELECT count(*) FROM MOL.Table2 e WHERE e.MyColumn2=73)` this selection is not used in group by or aggregation that's why you were getting error

you could do

```
 select sum(MyColumn1 -(SELECT count(*) FROM MOL.Table2 e WHERE e.MyColumn2=73))
from mol.Table1 where Column3=SomValue;
```

Comment: @user960567 i don't think in sql server it works because you have used aggregation so others selected column either you have to use in group by or that also need to put on aggregation

Comment: Just test yourself in SQL Server